# regarding wcf attributes and client/server communication

Tags: wcf

i do not know wcf but very soon i have to learn it. so i go through some online tutorial & small sample code. so some question has come into my mind like

1) why service must have one interface?

2) why service interface need to decorate with attribute like service contract?

3) why all interface method signature must decorate with operation contract.

4) what is the meaning of service contract & operation contract. what these attribute does actually.

5) what is data contract? when one method should be decorated with attribute like data contract.

6) i am familiar with web service. i saw web service was not related with any port but wcf is always related with port....why?

7) when i host a small hello world wcf service application in a console apps and start on remote machine then my client could not connect it. reason may was like port was not forwarded. some time we can host wcf but we can not enter into router so in that case we can not forward port. just tell me in that kind of situation how wcf client can connect to server?

8) can we create port and forward it programmatically when we host wcf on any remote machine.

if possible please discuss my points in details here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is a technology to transfer data between the client and the server.

You points 1 to 5, are all meant to tell WCF what is to be transfered, so that WCF can serialise the information on one side and deserialise it on the other,

For your point 6: WCF covers several technologies including web services. The default WCF configuration is the same as basic web services. Web services use port 80 by default.

For your point 7, either are  not pausing the console app, so it is not running when you try to  connect to it. Or the port you are using is blocked by the firewall.

On your point 8, WCF 4 supports routing.

Comment: i asked many things here and u cleverly avoid to give answer for all the points in detail. u event did not say what is service contract, operation contract and data contract. it would be great if u could discuss all points in detail.